Selenium Nodejs - Trying To Select Button
The HTML
<button class="RCK Hsu USg adn gn8 L4E kVc iyn S9z Vxj aZc Zr3 hA- Il7 hNT BG7" tabindex="0" type="submit">
     <div class="KS5 hs0 mQ8 un8 tkf TB_">
          <div class="xuA">
               <div class="tBJ dyH iFc sAJ B1n tg7 H2s">Log in</div>
          </div>
     </div>
</button>

The Code
...

await driver
      .findElement(
        By.css(
          "button.RCK.Hsu.USg.adn.gn8.L4E.kVc.CCY.S9z.Vxj.aZc.Zr3.hA-.Il7.hNT.BG7"
        )
      )
      .click(); 

...

The Error
NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button.RCK.Hsu.USg.adn.gn8.L4E.kVc.CCY.S9z.Vxj.aZc.Zr3.hA-.Il7.hNT.BG7"}

The Problem
I'm trying to select the button above using Selenium. I've been able to select other elements using xpath and id. But I've been unable to select the button shown above. Ideally I would want the button selected. I tried xpath and css but nothing is working. Can someone help me out?

The css that you are using button.RCK.Hsu.USg.adn.gn8.L4E.kVc.CCY.S9z.Vxj.aZc.Zr3.hA-.Il7.hNT.BG7" has multiple classes and they all are dynamic in nature. So what you are seeing in the browser won't be same when browser is invoked by the code.
I would suggest you go for a stable locator, I know xpath with text is not a very good practice but with the limited html shared, that's all I could write.
await driver
      .findElement(
        By.xpath("//div[text()='Log in']")).click();


No this wasn't the case as the CSS classes were not dynamic (I made sure of that). I managed to fix the problem by accessing it another way. I still wonder why it didn't work however
